# Increase or decrease website size

Tags: html, web, size, resolution

So, I made this website (lemiart.com) and depending on the image height (if it's too big), the user has to scroll down to view the entire image, specially when using computers with low res. What I would like to do is implement a button in the website so the user can click it and the website will become smaller, like decreasing the zoom in the browser. But I would like to implement it so the user just click it and it zooms out, without having to access the browser config.

Any idea on how to implement it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the best way is to set the default (max-)height of your images in CSS to a sensible value, I don't know, maybe 450px or something. Then download a pre-written javascript from the net that shows the full picture in a popup div when you click it, I'm sure there are plenty free code files available and the effect will be better than whatever you could write in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: The main problem is that I already made the website for the fixed width of 700 px in the image. I wouldn't like to change the image width, just allow the user to zoom in or out, depending on his needs. The reason is that only a few images don't look good, so i don't want to change all of them just to make these few look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like 'responsive web design'. Rather than have the user initiate an interaction (button click) to zoom or resize the site and images, consider adding some JQuery or other tools that detect the browser dimensions, and automatically reconfigure the page. This is a common approach when designing for multiple platforms (PC, mobile, tablet, etc).

[Check out this presentation](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like what I am looking for, but it seems to be a little bit complex. Do you think there is a way of making website smaller with buttons?

Comment: Not really. The javascript code to detect browser size and re-size the page elements will be similar no matter what, the only question is if it will get launched on a button click, or automatically when the page is loaded. There isn't any cross-browser built-in functionality that will take care of this automatically

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at some kind of lightbox plugin for jquery.

Fancybox(http://fancybox.net/) is one I have used that is quite good. With these you can have a smaller image on the site and then use the lightbox to zoom to the biiger one.

Comment: It is a great alternative, but I would like to try the zoom in and out before. I don't like the idea of clicking the image to view it in a larger scale. I think the main idea of the website is scroll down and apreciate the "art". If necessary, zoom out and view it smaller.

Comment: I think you have to consider how people use the Internet too. People are used to the 'gallery' idea and are happy to click to view a larger version. In some ways what you are trying to do seems counter intuitive - to me anyway - but its you website. You might find some of these useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207508/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-image-using-jquery