# how to zoom in and out a part of the screen on mouse move on jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have  some images. I want to zoom in whenever mouse goes and zoom out when mouse leaves. 
I have two 'Div's on top of each other, each contains a canvas and some draggable/droppable images. I want to zoom in whenever mouse goes and zoom out when mouse leaves. I would really appreciate any help. Warm regards . like the images are showing bigger in yahoo search

Comment: Please refer to [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207508/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-image-using-jquery?rq=1

*POSSIBLE DUPLICATE*

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a third party jquery plugin like this: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

Comment: i want images are zoomed like yahoo images